# Script to spread each file to its associated directory

Tags: scripts

The scenario is:

I have a directory with thousands of pictures in the format `YYYYMMDDXXX`

```
YYYY: stands for year
MM: stands for month
DD: stands for day
XXX: stands for an ID of the picture, it ranges from 1 to n characters
```

**The needed:**

Move each picture to the folder of that day. I,e, read name of picture suppose its name is `201504121A`, then this picture will be moved to directory named `12-04-2015` then rename it from `201504121A` to just ID which means `1A`. If this directory is not founded then create it.

Comment: 12-04-2015? Not smart... I would use 2015-04-12 where 04 is month and 12 the day. That way they order nicely when using `ls`. What you want can be done with pyrenamer if you want ( https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pyrenamer/ )

Comment: I need this format, related to system policy here

Comment: I used pyrenamer before but i want full script to create directories and move files to automatically, there are huge number of files here, thousands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i
do
    f="${i##*/}"
    y="${f:0:4}"
    m="${f:4:2}"
    d="${f:6:2}"
    x="${f:8}"
    mkdir -p "$d-$m-$y" && mv "$i" "$d-$m-$y/$x"
done
```

Save it as a script (say, `mover.sh`) and do:

```
/path/to/mover.sh *
```

Or:

```
find /path/to/pics -type f -exec /path/to/mover.sh {} +
```

Use a `echo` instead of `mkdir` and `mv` to test-drive it.

- `f="${i##*/}"` - get the filename stripping directory components.
- `y="${f:0:4}"`, and the other four - get the substrings at that position of that length.

Or, using regular expressions instead of substrings, with the benefit of actually testing for the pattern as well:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i
do
    f="${i##*/}"
    if [[ $f =~ ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.*) ]]
    then
        y="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        m="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        d="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        x="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
        mkdir -p "$d-$m-$y" && mv "$i" "$d-$m-$y/$x"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be a veteran Linux / Unix user.But i will write the instructions considering that you are a new linux user like me so that I don't miss something out from my part...

**Warning!!!**

**Before executing this script make sure that you have made backup of all the images on which you want to run this script to do operation..
There are many variables like naming convention word count etc which can affect the outcome of the execution. Please make sure that you backup your data..Nothing will be deleted but the script may change your filenames irregularly if there are any problem.**

**Don,t run this script if any image contains ID of more than 2 characters.
  As you mentioned before**
"XXX: stands for an ID of the picture, it ranges from 1 to n characters"

" and gave an example of " suppose its name is 201504121A, then this picture will be moved to directory named 12-04-2015 then rename it from 201504121A to just ID which means 1A"

**The ID of the pictures should be something like 1A 1B 1C 12 C 22 etc....You get my point ...It should be 2 characters and not one character like 1 2 3 ... or 3 characters like 222 666 777 etc...it should be exactly 2..If there is some images like that...i recommend that you modify my code to suit your purpose and always remember to back up your data before execution of the script.**

Written in Bash

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Developed by Sayan Bhattacharjee Date:26th may 2015 Tuesday Time 4:46PM IST
# conatact :zehel2892@gmail.com or askubuntu.com  Username:Sayan Bhatttacharjee
#More updates may come if required....
#Feel free to modify and redistribute this script
echo "Enter the extension of the files"
echo "like .jpg .png .bmp etc"
echo "make sure to enter . before the extension"
read extension
ls *$extension  > filenames
echo "Showing all the files of the extension present in the following directory"
cat filenames
echo "Checking line read option"
## while it reads line by line it will perform the required actions
while read line
do
echo "==============================================================="
    imageName=$line # updates the name of the image one by one in each loop according to how they are saved in the file
    echo "Imagefile is - $name"
    echo "Running file name resolver"
    echo "Running year resolver"

    year=${imageName:0:4 } #takes 4 lettters from the front
    echo "Year is $year"
    echo "Running month resolver"
    abc=${imageName: (-10) } # it will extract 10 characters from  the end   of 201504121A.jpg to produce 04121A.jpg

    month=${abc:0:2 } #It takes two characters from front of 04121A.jpg to produce 04

    echo "month is $month"
    echo "Running day resolver" 
    abc1=${imageName: (-8) } # it will extract 8 characters from  the end   of 201504121A.jpg to produce 121A.jpg
    day=${abc1:0:2 } #It takes two characters from front of 121A.jpg to produce 12
    echo "day is $day"

    echo "Running ID resolver"
    abc2=${imageName: (-6) }  # it will extract 6 characters from  the end   of 201504121A.jpg to produce 1A.jpg
    ID=${abc2:0:2 } #It takes two characters from front of 1A.jpg to produce 1A
    echo "$ID"
echo "Present Working Directory is"
pwd > base.txt #saving present working directory
baseDirectory=`cat base.txt`
echo "$baseDirectory"
echo ".............................................................."
echo "Running Directory creation and Image Insertion"
echo "Directory will not be created if it exists"
mkdir $day-$month-$year
echo "moving image and renaming it........"
mv $baseDirectory/$year$month$day$ID$extension $baseDirectory/$day-$month-$year/$ID$extension
cd $day-$month-$year
#echo "Present Working Sub Directory is"
#pwd > subpwd.txt #saving present working directory
#presentWorkingSubDirectory=`cat subpwd.txt`
#echo "$presentWorkingSubDirectory"
echo "Returning to Base Directory"
cd $baseDirectory
echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
done < filenames
echo "execution finished"
```

Save the code block in text file as `dataOrganiser.sh` (or any other name you prefer; but extension should be `.sh`).
**Make sure that the dataOrganiser.sh is in the directory where all your images are.. otherwise it will not work and you have to manually configure it**...
**Also be aware that it will be able to work on image files of only one extension at a time....for example it will work on .jpg first then .png and others....the choice of extension will be given to you on runtime..It is also possible to use it on other file formats like .txt .doc .pdf etc**

Then give executable authority to the dataOrganiser.sh  file by typing

```
 sudo chmod 755 /path/to/dataOrganiser.sh
```

755 will give you read write and execute authority and read and write authority to others . you will be asked for your password ..enter it to run as sudo.
Now execute the script by typing

```
/path/to/file/dataOrganiser.sh
```

After the script has started..you will be asked to give the extension of the images...you can give only one kind of extension at a time. And the extensions that can be given should be made of three alphabets like jpg bmp png gif etc. **Anything like tiff will not work..you have to modify the script.....again make sure you backup the images**

**When asked to enter the extension name enter it as .jpg or .bmp or .png or .gif because you need to give the .(dot before the extension to work)..**

**Did you remember to backup earlier??**..if you didnt close the program backup and come back to re-execute the program.....I dont want to cause any harm to someone's data

I have given all the information that comes into my head right now..please make sure that you follow all the instructions given above and again **Did you remember to backup your pictures**

Comment: Please make sure to copy everything correctly from the code block...This is my first time so it seems the code became quite long

Comment: +1 for your effort, but i think muru answer is better and much easier and shorter